# Python equivalent code for this CURL command?

Tags: python, curl

Below is my CURL command :

```
curl -v -X POST --cert ~/Desktop/cert/hardening.qa.pkcs:0JMQqqksE7Q2 --cert-type p12 https://somewebsite.com/SomeServers/PublishQueue/a.qa.queue.z -d'[{"count":5,"requeue":true,"encoding":"auto","truncate":50000}]'
```

Certificate file is : `~/Desktop/cert/hardening.qa.pkcs`
Certificate password : `0JMQqqksE7Q2`

I need to write the same code in Python, can someone please help me with requests library. I am not able to figure out how to add `--cert` and `--cert-type` in the requests.post

```py
resp = requests.post(url, json = data, cert = (cert_path,cert_pass), verify = False)
```

Comment: https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification

Comment: But how to mention in the code that this is a p12 certificate?

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests

if __name__=='__main__':
    url='https://somewebsite.com/SomeServers/PublishQueue/a.qa.queue.z'
    data=[{"table":"A","count":500},{"table":"B","count":1500}]
    cert_path='~/hardening.qa.pem'
    resp=requests.post(url,json=data,cert=cert_path)
    print(resp.status_code)
    print(resp.text)
    print(resp.headers)
```

The Problem was the certificate was in P12 format, I converted it to .pem file and the above code worked.